# how to remove default cordova icon from ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework

After installing app in android phone ,this cordova image is splashing before app start , anyone have an idea how to remove this ???

[image]

Answer (score -2):

[Add splash and app icon in Ionic Apps](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html)

Comment: i added splash and app icons ,but still its showing d same :(

Comment: Solved here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-app-icon-splash-issues/69894/4